# What female mathematician can I introduce to my High School students?

Tags: secondary-education, examples, history, women

I enjoy talking about Pythagoras when I teach the Pythagorean theorem. I sometimes mention Descartes when introducing Cartesian coordinates. And Leibniz and Newton are mentioned in many calculus classes. But all of these famous mathematicians accessible to high school students are male.

**What *female* mathematician can I introduce to my high school students? And what mathematical concept did she work with?**

Comment: See the book [*Women in Mathematics*](http://www.amazon.com/Women-Mathematics-Lynn-M-Osen/dp/0262650096) by Lynn M. Osen for several good examples.

Comment: What do you say about Pythagoras?  I'd want to emphasize that stories about him are less reliable than stories about Johnny Appleseed.

Comment: [Ada Lovelace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_lovelace) and [Vi Hart](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOGeU-1Fig3rrDjhm9Zs_wg)

Comment: Marie Curie and her daughter Irene Jeliot-Curie, while not mathematicians *per se*, combined for 3 Nobel prizes between them in Physics, Chemistry and Medicine and were most certainly competent in Mathematics.

Comment: Few if any of the results that high school students will rely on are attributable to women. You can't much work around that because it's a feature of the syllabus, the difficulty of modern mathematics, and the small number of pre-modern female mathematicians. I can't think of an example not of the form, "here is an impressive female mathematician, here is why her work was important, but you won't be using that". AP classes might get near, but for example Emmy Noether's work starts after an average undergraduate algebra syllabus stops.

Comment: a feminist argument for advancing the endpoint of American undergraduate education in mathematics ?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook: maybe, although personally I doubt the feminist value of introducing just a single "smurfette" into a population of smurfs. Perhaps instead an overview of more recent mathematics, introducing advanced concepts? Personally it doesn't make me feel any more misogynist to know that almost all the simple maths that I'm capable of understanding was first done by men (my degree is MMath). But educators will want to avoid the impression mathematics is *still* all men. A female Fields medallist would make that task easier, but you can't just manufacture one...

Comment: Although what Steve says is largely true of the high school curriculum, it's very much false of the undergraduate curriculum.  Emmy Noether work is really fundamental to the modern approach to algebra, and the way undergraduate algebra is taught is basically following her approach. (For example she was the first to give the definition of a ring.)

Comment: Also there was no Fields medal when Noether was under 40.  You don't need to manufacture a female Fields medalist, as Noether was clearly a more important mathematician than the average Fields medalist.

Comment: @Matt http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pythagoras/ for a source on the comment

Comment: not a "famous" mathematician, but Saramoira Shields made an excellent video about her experiences and perspectives with her major: http://youtu.be/Xs9aGVUZ3YA

Comment: An inspiring example of a teen-ager who did some nice math: [Britney Gallivan](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/174017/18398)

Comment: In addition to Ada Lovelace, you could introduce [Grace Hopper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper) and talk about computers (and [bugs](http://www.computerhistory.org/tdih/September/9) - the bug is visible [here](http://grahamcluley.com/2013/09/first-actual-computer-bug/), and she popularized the story).

Comment: I protected this since we start getting some duplicate and near duplicate answers.

Comment: What about Mary Anne Ruden?

Comment: Ada Lovelace's role is usually vastly exaggerated, she is NOT a good example.  Also be careful in the way that you present them not to further the idea that girls need female role models and should not be inspired by the men too. If you identify as a person (not a gender) and are inspired by people you are much more likely to get further in life.

Comment: @Noah: thanks, I didn't know (or knew but forgot) that the axioms are hers. Rings make an interesting case I suppose, in that Noether has re-founded something that earlier mathematicians were already doing in a less good way (and she then did things they hadn't done before, ofc, which is what I was thinking of as beyond typical undergrad). I guess I completely missed that some of the definitions that follow from rings in the syllabus are restatements of gadgets that pre-date the ring abstraction.

Comment: @SteveJessop: There's an earlier definition of ring due to Fraenkel, but it's somewhere between our modern notions of field and commutative ring.  But Noether's the first to give the essentially modern definition of a commutative ring and to really conceive of ring theory as such.  The story for ideals is similar (they were used before, but the fully modern development that you'd see in an algebra class is Noether's).  The isomorphism theorems (which are often the capstone of an undergrad algebra class) are hers.

Comment: Apart from the link from @MichaelE2, there is also [MacTutor History of Mathematics archive: Female mathematicians](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Indexes/Women.html), and there is [Wikipedia: List of female mathematicians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_female_mathematicians).

Comment: @MattF: Yes, you're right. The stories about Pythagoras are quite unreliable, but it's still fun to share them with students who don't appreciate Greek history nearly as much as they should. One time I even tried dressing up like Pythagoras, which was quite a blast.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't post this as an answer because the question has been protected: [Ingrid Daubechies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingrid_Daubechies) known for the Daubechies wavelet which can e.g. be used to compress images (and thus speeding up viewing web pages, something which high school students probably find relevant...)

Comment: @Rustyn  I suspect you mean [Mary Ellen Rudin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Ellen_Rudin)

Comment: http://xkcd.com/896/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain

Comment: If I asked the same question but replaced "female" with "Muslim", then people would/should say that "religion shouldn't matter. What's the purpose behind the question?" I would agree with this sentiment, and I think it applies to the question asked here also. So what is the purpose behind *this* question (the one with "female")? If you answer, "because women can aspire to be like her/ look up to her/whatever", then the same can be said if we replaced "women" with "Muslim", or "blond hair colour", or "tall people" or "short people", ...

Comment: ...or any number of other things that *don't matter with regards to what should be considered good motivation for studying mathematics*. So my question stands: what is the point of this question?

Answer (score 91):

[Emmy Noether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmy_Noether) comes first to mind, as one of the most influential mathematicians in abstract algebra, specifically in the development of Noetherian rings (along with many properties of ideals).

One aspect of her work that high school students might like is from another area, analysis. [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) says that every symmetry of the laws of nature (or the universe) gives rise to a Conservation Law.

So, energy is conserved because of time symmetry (meaning that the laws of nature don't change after time).

Momentum is conserved because of translation symmetry (meaning that the laws of nature are the same at every point).

Angular momentum is conserved because of rotation symmetry (meaning that the laws of nature are the same in every direction).

**Edit:** Recently I've learned that, in quantum mechanics, Noether's theorem has quite a few more implications. For instance, the fact that the phase factor is redundant (i.e. the direction of the complex number that you square to get a probability) gives rise to conservation of charge, and quite a few other things get conserved in QFT.

Comment: Noether's theorem is probably going to seem quite mind-blowing to anyone who isn't able to follow its mathematical derivation. Which could be a good or bad thing. ;-)

Comment: Even if you can't follow the derivation of Noether's theorem the examples are still pretty cool.  It's pretty intuitive once it's pointed out that momentum should be related to shift symmetry and angular momentum to rotational symmetry (and then you can blow their minds with time shift symmetry and energy).

Answer (score 65):

**[Julia Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_Robinson)!** I recommend her for a high school audience for a few reasons:

*Mathematical reasons:* She is best known for her work towards the solution of [Hilbert's 10th Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Tenth_Problem), regarding an algorithm for solving Diophantine Equations. High school students can absolutely recognize and solve particular Diophantine Equations. Furthermore, and more relevant to Robinson's work, I believe high school students can appreciate (upon seeing examples) the subtle dependence of such equations on their coefficients.

For instance, ask a high school algebra student to experiment and find all the solutions to, say, $6x+15y=33$. Then, ask them to solve $6x+15y=34$. What changes? Give them some random coefficients for $ax+by=c$. What would they do? Can they generalize to more variables?

Then, work with them on a quadratic equation, something like $x^2+1=y^2$. Can they find any solutions? What about $3x^2-5y^2=2$? Do they see how hard it is to get a general method?

Then, you can start to talk about what Hilbert's 10th Problem says. This can facilitate several interesting discussions for a high school audience

- Solving equations in integers (Why have mathematicians been interested in solving them since pretty much antiquity? Where do they appear in real life?)
- Algorithms and decision procedures (What is an algorithm? What makes one better than another? Do we care about how *efficiently* they can run, or how *easy* they are to describe/implement?)
- Logic and philosophy of mathematics (What does it mean to *prove* something? What does it mean to *disprove* something? What does it mean to prove that there is *no procedure* that could solve every Diophantine equation?)

(I understand this doesn't *really* address the full depth of Hilbert's 10th, but if you're looking to pique the interest of a high school audience, I believe this should suffice.)

---

*Historical reasons:* Julia Robinson is one of the more notable and renowned mathematicians (no need for "female") of the 20th century, especially in America. Despite this, she had difficulty securing an academic position. But despite *that*, she went on to obtain such a position and became the first female president of the AMS. Along the way, she devoted much of her time to other interests, including political campaigns.

Surely, she can spark many interesting discussions for a high school audience!

Comment: Another good J.R. topic is one of the "positive aspects of a negative solution":  there is a polynomial whose positive values are exactly the primes.

Comment: +1: It is hard for me to imagine *anyone* who would not regard Julia Bowman Robinson as being an inspirational figure in one manner or another.

Answer (score 53):

Perhaps not strictly a mathematician in the traditional sense, but I think [**Ada Lovelace**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace) might be a great woman to start with in today's digital world. She even has an important programming language named after her: [**Ada**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ada/info).

> Augusta Ada King, Countess of Lovelace (10 December 1815 – 27 November
>   1852), born Augusta Ada Byron and now commonly known as Ada Lovelace,
>   **was an English mathematician** and writer chiefly known for her work on
>   Charles Babbage's early mechanical general-purpose computer, the
>   Analytical Engine. Her notes on the engine include what is recognised
>   as the first algorithm intended to be carried out by a machine.
>   **Because of this, she is often described as the world's first computer programmer**.

Or, if you choose to go with the ancients, I'd suggest [**Hypatia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypatia):

> Hypatia (/haɪˈpeɪʃə/ hy-PAY-shə; Ancient Greek: Ὑπατία; Hypatía) (born
>   c. AD 350 – 370; died 415) was a Greek Alexandrine Neoplatonist
>   philosopher in Egypt **who was one of the earliest mothers of
>   mathematics. As head of the Platonist school at Alexandria,** she also
>   taught philosophy and astronomy.
>
> As a Neoplatonist philosopher, she belonged to the mathematic
>   tradition of the Academy of Athens, as represented by Eudoxus of
>   Cnidus; she was of the intellectual school of the 3rd century thinker
>   Plotinus, which encouraged logic and mathematical study in place of
>   empirical enquiry and strongly encouraged law in place of nature.

Recent scholarship has determined that certain important commentaries were indeed written by Hypatia:

> [**Hypatia also wrote
>   commentaries**](http://news.bbc.co.uk/dna/place-lancashire/plain/A481006)
>   on the Arithmetica of Diophantus, the Conics of Apollonious and edited
>   part of her father's Commentary on the Almagest by Ptolemy.

[**Hypatia also met with a rather unfortunate end**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypatia):

> According to the only contemporary source, Hypatia was murdered by a
>   Christian mob after being accused of exacerbating a conflict between
>   two prominent figures in Alexandria: the governor Orestes and the
>   Bishop of Alexandria.

More details @ [**Events leading to her murder**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypatia#Death). She was at times something of a popular romantic icon as well. See: [**In the 19th century, interest in the "literary legend of Hypatia" began to rise**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypatia#19th_century).

Perhaps the dramatic aspects of Hypatia's life could be deemed distractions from her accomplishments in mathematics, when dealing with HS students. On the other hand, since her story is interesting and provocative, it might well serve to foster students' interest in her accomplishments.

Comment: I recommend against discussing Hypatia, since we have nothing written by her.  How would you answer the OP's question:  What mathematical concept did she work with?

Comment: My citations explain that. BTW, recent scholarship has determined that certain important commentaries  were indeed written by Hypatia. See [Hypatia also wrote commentaries on the Arithmetica of Diophantus, the Conics of Apollonious and edited part of her father's Commentary on the Almagest by Ptolemy.](http://news.bbc.co.uk/dna/place-lancashire/plain/A481006)

Comment: I'd be hesitant to use her as an example due to the potential distraction from how she died.  I've seen a number of cases where someone tried to insist she was murdered for being a woman in science; not for her long term involvement in the blood sport known as Alexandrian politics.

Comment: @DanNeely - _where someone tried to insist she was murdered for being a woman in science_  - that contention is absurd to anyone who knows anything about the ancient Greeks, and perhaps bringing her up will open the door to educating kids about good History and the role of women in the ancient world, which seems to be related to what the OP is interested in. Otherwise, why the question at all?

Comment: [Additional insight for Ada Lovelace](http://www.ted.com/talks/john_graham_cumming_the_greatest_machine_that_never_was)

Comment: For another influential female computer scientist, there is Grace Hopper: http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2516

Comment: A newish [**piece**](https://medium.com/backchannel/untangling-the-tale-of-ada-lovelace-4cbca62898b6) by Stephen Wolfram on **Ada Lovelace**.

Answer (score 52):

Florence Nightingale, elected to the Royal Statistical Society and (honorarily) to the American Statistical Association, for her work on the importance of statistical data and statistical graphics.

Her statistics and her graphics persuaded the British government to improve sanitation in military hospitals, saving many soldiers' lives.

She was a statistician rather than a mathematician, but since statistics is part of high school math classes, she seems worth talking about.

Comment: It is worth noting that according to some sources (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_chart) she popularised / invented the use of pie charts.

Comment: @Rune, she popularized/invented a *variant* of pie charts -- a creative variant that worked for her, but not a format I would advise students to use.  If I showed those charts in a class, I would ask: "How else might you present this data to make it clear and visually striking?"

Comment: +1 Florence Nightingale was one of the first people to successfully use statistics and data visualisation to bring around a direct change in government policy which saved lives and changed the history of war and medicine. It's a perfect example of how maths can change the world, with loads to interest children (war *and* nursing *and* surprising counter-intuitive facts: she proved that more soldiers were dying of infections in dirty field hospitals than from battle, which led to modern nursing). She was genuinely one of the top pioneers in her field (nothing to do with her gender).

Comment: Brilliant idea. There is vast potential here for interdisciplinary ideas, and a good reminder that not all of the people who developed statistics and probability were into gambling!

Comment: @user867 I agree, not all of the pioneer statisticians were into gambling -- some were into eugenics!

Comment: Farming too.  (It is a multifactorial problem with some uncontrolled factors requiring repeats to factor out noise.)  And kind of important.  Gotta eat.  And one that is rather physically intuitive.

Answer (score 45):

[Sophie Germain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain) and her work on Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: Germain primes are a very accessible mathematical starting point.

Comment: I remember doing a report on her in 6th grade. But I remember boundary constrained differential equations (well, I didn't know that's what they were at the time).

Comment: I often quote Sophie Germain to elementary math students, saying, "Algebra is but written geometry and geometry is but figured algebra," or some slight paraphrase of that. I find this relevant when doing any kind of analytic geometry, and seeing the same facts revealed geometrically as well as in formulas.

Answer (score 40):

[Maryam Mirzakhani](http://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/maryam-mirzakhani-becomes-1st-woman-to-win-fields-medal-1.2734950), who just won the Fields Medal, and also was the first Iranian student to win a gold medal in the IMO in 1995 with a perfect score.

My colleague Mohammad Javaheri was on Iran's IMO team with her in 1995. He told us the other day that after Maryam won the gold, when the rest of the team went up to congratulate her she said "next, the Fields Medal". Nineteen years later, she did it!

(I'm not sure what else to say that would be interesting to high school students...as moduli spaces of Riemann surfaces may not be so interesting to them...)

Comment: This is especially relevant now. As for the last sentence, it would be worth mentioning that she helped bridge the gap between probability theory and geometry (?) the common pool table analogy seems particularly effective with kids, although she gave her preferred example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxPE6vYwqLg)

Comment: Today's news was heartbreaking. Thanks for the link, Andres.

Answer (score 39):

**Any Living One** who is friendly enough to come talk with them.

Seriously, learning about "people in books" can sometimes be inspiring. But actual live role models are best. Write a local college, university, or business to find a woman who self-identifies as a mathematician. Invite her to your school to spend some time with your students. You want a real person who happens to be a mathematician, a woman, and reasonably happy about that arrangement.

I feel awkward about leaving out women who might be working as mathematics instructors in your school, because I think they count as part of the community, too. But students are used to the whole "female high school teacher" archetype, and you seem like you want to adjust their view of normal jobs for women mathematicians, so you are better off finding someone new.

Answer (score 29):

**Edit (Jan 2018)** I recommend checking Annie Perkins' page:

> [**The Mathematicians Project: Mathematicians Are Not Just White Dudes**](https://arbitrarilyclose.com/2016/08/21/the-mathematicians-project-mathematicians-are-not-just-white-dudes/)

If you scroll down, then you will find a section entitled **Women (alphabetical by last name)**.

There are some great sources/names there, and - as a bonus - the project keeps evolving!

$$ $$

$$ $$

$$ $$

---

**Edit:** Marjorie Rice has recently passed away; for more on her life, see the Quantum story [**here**](https://www.quantamagazine.org/marjorie-rices-secret-pentagons-20170711/).

---

I think [Marjorie Rice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marjorie_Rice) is a great example of an amateur mathematician who managed to make nontrivial discoveries with regard to tessellations. Interestingly, her notation was deciphered by a female professor of mathematics, [Doris Schattschneider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doris_Schattschneider) (also [here](http://www.agnesscott.edu/lriddle/women/schatt.htm)), who helped to lead the development of Geometer's Sketchpad. (Perhaps you use this piece of software in your school?)

Another great choice is [Mary Dolciani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_P._Dolciani) (also [here](http://www.nctm.org/resources/content.aspx?id=2912)) who was a Ph.D mathematician especially known for her teaching abilities, and a prolific writer of textbooks and curricula (e.g., through the School Mathematics Study Group, SMSG, which developed New Math). I included a bit about her in an earlier MESE [answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/369/was-there-an-smsg-new-math-algebra-2-text/806#806).

Comment: (A [**recent update**](http://www.theguardian.com/science/alexs-adventures-in-numberland/2015/aug/10/attack-on-the-pentagon-results-in-discovery-of-new-mathematical-tile) on tessellating pentagons!)

Comment: (& an even [**more recent update**](https://www.quantamagazine.org/pentagon-tiling-proof-solves-century-old-math-problem-20170711/)!)

Comment: Why does this have two down votes? If you leave a comment, then I can try to address it...

Answer (score 29):

[Vi Hart](http://www.youtube.com/user/Vihart), the self-termed *Mathemusician*. I especially enjoy her [Doodling in Math Class](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC20F52B96F3E8206) YouTube series.

Comment: I really think this answer needs more attention. Her videos were really inspiring for me in high school.

Comment: They're inspiring for me and I've already graduated from college!

Comment: This girl is awsome and very inspiring. She should definitely be a female mathematician model for high school students, firstly because she can easily inspire them, and also because she has worked on things that high school students can understand. I have created an account here, just to upvote your answer

Comment: She's working as part of [elevr](http://elevr.com/about-us/) which is a VR research group, of which one part is [exploring mathematics via VR](http://elevr.com/tag/math/). The other women she is working with are all interesting in their own right too.

Answer (score 28):

Sonya Kovalevsky, correspondent of Weierstrass, for example.

Comment: She won the *Prix Bordin* for her work on what is now known as the [Kovalevsky top](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kovalevskaya_Top), and she proved the full version of the [Cauchy-Kovalevsky theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Kovalevski_theorem), which stood for nearly 50 years as the central result in the theory of partial differential equations, until the theory of weak solutions came along.

Answer (score 25):

If your main interest is to provide a role model that students can identify with, you might want to look at [Danica McKellar.](http://www.danicamckellar.com/)  According to [her Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danica_McKellar):

> McKellar studied mathematics at UCLA, graduating *summa cum laude* in 1998.
>
> As an undergraduate, she coauthored a scientific paper with Professor Lincoln Chayes and fellow student Brandy Winn entitled "Percolation and Gibbs states multiplicity for ferromagnetic Ashkin-Teller models on $\mathbb{Z}^2$." Their results are termed the 'Chayes–McKellar–Winn theorem'.
>
> [...]
>
> McKellar has authored several mathematics-related books primarily targeting adolescent readers [those in middle-school and high-school] interested in succeeding at the study of mathematics.

Comment: This was going to be my answer! She was World News' Person of the Week (http://youtu.be/nXsfBQlXb6Y) and her Math Doesn't Suck book has great reviews.

Comment: Winnie Cooper from The Wonder Years! That's pretty awesome (for anyone that still remembers).

Answer (score 23):

Classically speaking, [Maria Agnesi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Gaetana_Agnesi) is the best classical mathematician to study.  She published calculus texts that expanded and reflected upon the works of Leonhard Euler.

Comment: There is also a curve called the Witch of Agnesi.

Comment: Yes.  This is one to mention in calculus class.  Although women were not allowed in the university, she learned mathematics from her father, a professor of mathematics at the University of Pisa.  In later years, on occasion she would substitute for her father when he was away ... although the rules prohibited women students, there was (through oversight) no rule prohibiting women instructors...

Answer (score 20):

Adm. [Grace Hopper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper) earned a Ph.D. in mathematics at Yale (1934), helped program the Mark I (1944), developed the first compiler (1952) and some early computer languages, and worked on the development of the UNIVAC I.

Answer (score 18):

[Maria Gramegna](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Gramegna), the brilliant student of Giuseppe Peano.

When you use matrices to solve systems of differential equations, you rely in many ways to [her ideas](http://books.google.hu/books?id=U3k8yfchaPYC&lpg=PA505&ots=8YEC34fNK8&dq=maria%20gramegna%20peano&hl=de&pg=PA504#v=onepage&q=maria%20gramegna%20peano&f=false). She defined the exponential function of a matrix through its power series and used it as we do it now. Though this is not strictly speaking high school mathematics, you can mention her story to every undergraduate.

She also generalized this to infinite systems and integrodifferential equations, and many ideas of her 1910 thesis belong to the foundation of functional analysis.

After that, she became a school teacher and died in an earthquake in 1915.

Answer (score 15):

[Grace Chisholm Young](http://www.agnesscott.edu/lriddle/women/young.htm) seems overlooked so far (13 answer so far) and in my opinion she is worth considering. She worked mostly in real analysis and what is sometimes called classical point set theory (among other things, she's the "Young" in the Denjoy-Young-Saks theorem and she wrote a well known survey paper on nowhere differentiable continuous functions in 1916), and she played a large role in her husband's 200+ papers.

Besides math, she knew 6 languages, completed all the requirements for a medical degree except for residency, had 6 children in a period of 9 years, and wrote a book on reproduction for children. Despite all her activities, she was also very devoted to her children (teaching each to play a musical instrument), who went on to become: both a son and a daughter were fairly well known mathematicians (the son was also a chess grandmaster), a daughter became a medical doctor and the first female member of the Royal College of Surgeons, a son earned a Ph.D. in chemistry at University of Oxford and later pursued public finance and diplomacy, a daughter completed an undergraduate degree in math and was an Associate Professor of French at Bryn Mawr from 1927 to 1935, a son earned an undergraduate engineering degree and was killed as a pilot in World War 1.

I recommend looking through Ivor Grattan-Guinness' 1972 paper *A mathematical union: William Henry and Grace Chisholm Young*, which contains many interesting details about her life.

Answer (score 14):

[Alicia Boole Stott](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alicia_Boole_Stott), the daughter of George Boole (Boolean Algebra), had a deep understanding of 4D geometry.  She got married and lived the life that entailed back then (1890s and on).  [Coxeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Scott_MacDonald_Coxeter) gives her husband some credit for connecting her to [Pieter Schoute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pieter_Schoute).  They worked together and published some papers on 4D polytopes.  Coxeter's book, [Regular Polytopes](http://books.google.com/books?id=2ee7AQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Regular+Polytopes&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lV5UU8LRDsWU8QGZz4CIBg&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Regular%20Polytopes&f=false) has a brief biography.  Coxeter worked with her later in her life.  George Boole's household was rather interesting according to Coxeter.  Alicia was introduced to 4D geometry through [C.H. Hinton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Howard_Hinton), who married her sister and wrote [a book](http://books.google.com/books?id=_ZG3MA1wvjIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Charles+Hinton+geometry&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6F9UU4KsJerT8gGjlIDwDQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) on the fourth dimension.

Comment: There is something wrong with the sentence "Coxeter gives her husband some credit for connecting her to Pieter Schoute". As Wikipedia shows and is probably well known, Coxeter is a man; however you write feminine adverb "her".

Comment: @kan Coxeter gives Alicia Stott's husband Walter credit for putting Alicia in contact with Pieter Schoute.  The "her" is Alicia Stott in both cases.

Comment: That is now very clear. Thanks for the clarification. I am not a native speaker as you probably figured but if you think it is appropriate, you could consider rewording your answer a little bit.

Answer (score 13):

I think for young girls [**Ruth Lawrence**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth_Lawrence) is a great role model since she got her phd at age of **17**:

> - At the age of 9, Ruth Lawrence gained an O-level in mathematics,    setting a new age record.
> - Also at the age of 9 she achieved a Grade A at A-level Pure    Mathematics.
> - In 1981 Ruth Lawrence passed the Oxford University interview entrance    examination in mathematics, coming first out of all 530
>     candidates    sitting the examination, and joining St Hugh's College
>     in 1983 at the    age of just twelve.

Another example would be [Shelly Harvey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelly_Harvey) from Rice University.

Comment: Under this answer I thought I'd mention [Lisa Sauermann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisa_Sauermann), whose accomplishments (IMO performances) are recent enough that most likely know of her.

Comment: RL is fairly controversial as a role model, as many people at the time felt that her father was using her to live out his own dreams of being an Oxford undergraduate (he accompanied her there).  (Only she is qualified to give a judgement on that.)  Also, while she is clearly very bright, she has not produced any groundbreaking work as an adult.

Comment: I'm not sure of the logic behind your first sentence: Does getting a Ph.D at a young age imply one is a great role model?

Answer (score 11):

More famous for computer science than maths, but a strong mathematician none the less and creator of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (the L in [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)), [Barbara Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Liskov).

Answer (score 11):

I have several daughters and I like talking to them about my female friends in the computer graphics industry. In particular, an acquaintance of mine, Kelly Ward, who did the physics (and math) for the hair in Disney's Tangled.

A few links:

http://www.gpb.org/blogs/passion-for-learning/2012/06/06/disneys-tangled-an-exercise-in-physics-and-computer-animation
http://unc.edu/meet-a-tar-heel/kelly-ward/

Answer (score 10):

The story of [Sarah Flannery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Flannery) may interest high school students, as she worked on non-trivial mathematics related to codes as a sixteen year old.

Answer (score 10):

While in high school [Britney Gallivan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britney_Gallivan) folded a piece of (very special) paper twelve times, when most people thought it couldn't be folded more than 7 or 8 times, and [wrote a paper about it](http://pomonahistorical.org/12times.htm).

Like the amateur mathematician, Marjorie Rice, mentioned in another answer, she shows that people who are deeply engaged in a problem can make advances, and that mathematics has room for new discoveries.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to Google Doodle, today I learned about [Olga Ladyzhenskaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olga_Ladyzhenskaya) and her fantastic life.

[image: screenshot of Google Doodle for Olga Ladyzhenskaya]

**From Wikipedia**. Ladyzhenskaya was born and grew up in Kologriv. She was the daughter of a mathematics teacher who is credited with her early inspiration and love of mathematics. In October 1939 her father was arrested by the NKVD and soon killed. Young Olga was able to finish high school but, because her father was an "enemy of the people", she was forbidden to enter the Leningrad University.
After the death of Joseph Stalin in 1953, Ladyzhenskaya presented her doctoral thesis and was given the degree she had long before earned. She went on to teach at the university in Leningrad and at the Steklov Institute, staying in Russia even after the collapse of the Soviet Union and the rapid salary deflation for professors.

Ladyzhenskaya was on the shortlist for potential recipients for the 1958 Fields Medal, ultimately awarded to Klaus Roth and René Thom.

**Her Mathematical Work.** She was known for her work on partial differential equations (especially Hilbert's nineteenth problem) and fluid dynamics.

I think some aspect of the fluid dynamics might be introduced in high school. There is an attempt [here](https://peer.asee.org/introducing-talented-high-school-students-to-engineering-via-fluid-mechanics.pdf). In particular, looking at the male-dominated history of the subject, I feel she should find her place in the photo used in the aforementioned attempt.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Émilie du Châtelet ,(17 December 1706  – 10 September 1749) was a French mathematician, physicist, and author during the Age of Enlightenment. Her crowning achievement is considered to be her translation and commentary on Isaac Newton's work Principia Mathematica. The translation, published posthumously in 1759, is still considered the standard French translation.

Voltaire, one of her lovers, declared in a letter to his friend King Frederick II of Prussia that du Châtelet was "a great man whose only fault was being a woman"

(From Wikipedia)

Answer (score 8):

[Ingrid Daubechies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingrid_Daubechies), known for [Daubechies wavelets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daubechies_wavelet) and former president of the [IMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mathematical_Union).

[Ruth Moufang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth_Moufang), known for [Moufang loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moufang_loop).

Answer (score 7):

**Mary Somerville** (1780-1872) was a self-taught mathematician and an expert on theoretical astronomy. The [***Dictionary of National Biography***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_of_National_Biography) (London, 1897) described her as 'the most remarkable woman of her generation'. See this [article](http://adsbit.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=1996JBAA..106..201B) about her.

Answer (score 6):

The Association for Women in Mathematics has a great annual essay contest. Here is a [link](https://sites.google.com/site/awmmath/programs/essay-contest/Past-Winning-Essays).  There are some great essays and the subjects run the gamut from industry to academia to the arts.

Answer (score 5):

### Shakuntala Devi a.k.a Human Calculator

Her talents eventually earned her a place in the 1982 edition of The Guinness Book of World Records.As a writer, Devi wrote a number of books, including novels and non-fiction texts about mathematics, puzzles, and astrology.

[Link to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakuntala_Devi)

[Other Human calculators](http://www.csmonitor.com/Innovation/2013/1104/Shakuntala-Devi-and-other-human-calculators)

Comment: While perhaps an interesting person, this woman is not a mathematician. Mental calculation is closer to magic (a kind of performance art or theater) than to mathematics.

Answer (score 5):

Whitman, Betsey S. Women of Mathematics: A Biobibliographic Sourcebook, Louise Grinstein and Paul Campbell, Editors, Greenwood Press, 1987.

Bailey, Martha J. American Women in Science: A Biographical Dictionary, ABC-CLIO, 1994.

Answer (score 5):

**[Karen Uhlenbeck](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Uhlenbeck_Karen.html)** ought to be mentioned. She made deep [contributions](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg1=INDI&s1=175775) in the theory of minimal immersions (more generally, harmonic maps), gauge theory of Yang Mills equations (the work of Taubes and Donaldson on four manifolds uses her work), wave maps, integrable systems (e.g. solitons, instantons), etc. She is one of the most important researchers in geometrically and physically motivated partial differential equations of her generation. Although her work as such is probably almost completely inaccessible to any but the most exceptional high school students, the study of soap films and minimal surfaces can be presented to high school students, and some part of her work treats themes that can be seen (in some distant way) as emerging from that source. Maybe something could also be said about solitons, which have applications in telecommunications (although Uhlenbeck's work is not oriented towards applications).

Although her mathematics is not the most accessible, she is a model example of a contemporary woman mathematician of the highest level intellectually and professionally. She has also been [active](http://www.math.ias.edu/wam/about/note) in promoting the participation of women in mathematics.

Comment: It should be added that she won the 2019 Abel Prize:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karen_Uhlenbeck

Answer (score 4):

I always make sure to mention Hypatia in my classes and at least show them parts of this video (The Story of Maths - Marcus Du Sautoy BBC). I've linked to the part where she's mentioned.

http://youtu.be/rDBdT1Dl_QY?t=55m6s

Comment: The video says "her cult status eclipsed her mathematical achievements" -- if I had time to discuss 30 mathematicians with a class, I wouldn't spend much time on one who requires a proviso like that.

Answer (score 2):

35 years ago Florence Nightingale was taught at my school to be the female mathematician to look up to because of her many disciplines.  However, I've replaced that image with Lady Ada Lovelace who is considered the first computer programmer.

Comment: Can you talk a little about what motivated you to make the switch and perhaps what you have noticed about any differences in how students talk about the two people? Has anything interesting happened in the wake of the switch?

Answer (score 2):

[Christine Ladd-Franklin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christine_Ladd-Franklin) was involved in the early development of a community of American Mathematical research. She was the first female student and Johns Hopkins (though unofficially enrolled) and produced results in algebraic logic.

Answer (score 1):

[Mary Kenneth Keller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Kenneth_Keller), also more of a computer scientist than a mathematician, but still.

Answer (score 1):

The "classic" female mathematician of the past century was Marie curie.

She was also a great chemist and physicist.

Comment: Could you add an example of her *mathematical* work? (I never heard her being referred to as a mathematician.)

Comment: quid: She graduated the Sorbonne with a "double major" in physics and math. "Chemistry" actually came later when she met (and married) Pierre. But maybe I was stretching a point because math came third after physics and chemistry.

Answer (score -3):

Since you are referring to High School students, I suggest a different approach. The women mentioned so far probably appeal to girls who are already interested in Math, but not to the masses. If you want to change the perception is that Math is "nerdy" and "uncool", here are some women (not Math necessarily, but technology) who are alive, cool, possibly even "hot" (A role model for teenage girls?)

- Limor "Ladyada" Fried
  She founded the Electronics company in 2005 and appeared on a hangout with president Obama in 2013
- Nixie Pixel (not sure about her real name)
  She makes Linux tutorials on Youtube
- Veronica Belmont
  A technology host for Revision3.com

Proof that a woman can be smart and "cute" at the same time!

Comment: The question asks for female mathematicians; you post about women in technology, and suggest them for also being "hot" and "cute." $-1$.

Comment: So what is your explanation for the relatively low participation of women in Mathematics, technology, and Engineering? What would you suggest to encourage women to participate more? Or are you comfortable with the status quo?

Comment: I'm not advocating for this answer since it is poorly constructed, but I do think something needs to be said about the stereotype of women in mathematics (and the other sciences) being "frumpy." The assumption can go another way, too: STEM Academics sometimes consider a woman who cares about her appearance to be diverting attention from her work.